# Possibility to specify a custom diff tool

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, difftool

Is it possible to specify a custom file comparison tool?

I noticed that e.g. notepad++ with the [comparePlus](https://github.com/pnedev/comparePlus) plugin is more powerful than the integrated comparer of VSC.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no. And intuitively, it doesn't make sense to me why an editor with builtin diff tooling would provide a in-baked mechanism to invoke an external diff tool on a file.

You can, however, do the following:

Copy the path to the file you want to open diff info for

- If that file is the currently active file, you can do this with the `File: Copy Path of Active File` (which is bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> on windows and linux).
- Otherwise, right click the file in the VS Code explorer, and then click the "Copy Path" menu item.

And then either:

- Configure what difftool is used by git when you invoke `git difftool`, which you can do from the terminal, and then invoke `git difftool` with the path to that file and whatever other arguments you want.
- Or directly invoke your tool of choice from the commandline (instead of through `git difftool`) and pass it that file's path.

You could also [write an extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) to do this and save yourself some steps.